# How to postulate a formula for the following Mathematica function

Tags: integer-sequence

I am using Mathematica to explore the properties of the Fibonacci Sequence. Below is the functions I have defined

```
H[n_] := \[Phi]^n/Sqrt[5]

F[n_] := Round[H[n]]

S[m_] := Sum[F[n], {n, 1, m}]
```

Through experimentation I have realised that `S[m]=SF[m-1]+F[m]`. How do I obtain a conjectured formula for this and prove it by induction?

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything further.

Comment: Are you aware that `Fibonacci[]` is built-in? Try this: `FullSimplify[Sum[Fibonacci[k], {k, 1, n}] == Fibonacci[n + 1] + Fibonacci[n] - 1, Element[n, Integers]]`

Comment: What is `SF[m]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
H[n_] = GoldenRatio^n/Sqrt[5];

S[m_] := Total@Round[H /@ Range[m] // FunctionExpand // Simplify]
```

Generate a sequence of `S[m]`

```
seq = S /@ Range[10]

(* {1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, 33, 54, 88, 143} *)
```

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find a function that generates the sequence

```
S2[m_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, m]

(* 1/2 (-2 + 3 Fibonacci[m] + LucasL[m]) *)
```

Verifying that `S` and `S2` are equivalent beyond the range of the original sequence

```
And @@ (Table[S[m] == S2[m], {m, 100}] // Simplify)

(* True *)
```

While `S[m]` is discrete, `S2[m]` is continuous.

```
Show[
  Plot[S2[m], {m, 0, 5.25}],
  DiscretePlot[S[m], {m, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Verifying your conjecture

```
S2[m] == S2[m - 1] + Fibonacci[m] // FunctionExpand // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: `Fibonacci[n + 2] - 1` would be a much simpler expression for the sum; the Identity for `S2` then reduces to the defining recursion for the Fibonacci numbers.